# How do I tell doxygen a function is "self-documenting"?

Tags: doxygen, code-documentation, self-documenting-code

I'm using Doxygen for my (C++) project.

I have some functions which are self-explanatory, for which I don't want to add any comment or explanation - but which I *do* want appearing as part of the documentation. Now, this does happen as doxygen's default behavior if I don't write a `/** */` block, but then - I get a warning in Doxygen's output:

```
warning: Member foo() of namespace bar is not documented.
```

How can I tell doxygen that it's fine that there's no documentation for such functions?

Additional information:

- I have `EXTRACT_ALL            = NO`
- I'm using Doxygen 1.8.13 on Devuan ASCII (~= Debian Stretch)

Comment: In your doxygen configuration file, what is the parameter `EXTRACT_ALL`  set to?

Comment: Please always specify the doxygen version used. @P.W Might have some side effects like extra not wanted functions.

Comment: @P.W: see edit.

Comment: @albert: See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen wants to see documentation for all functions it shows so you anyway have to do something.

Best would be to have an empty command for this like:

```
ALIASES = selfdocumenting="&nbsp;"
```

so you can write e.g.:

```
/// @selfdocumenting
void fie2(void);
```

Comment: But won't this create blocks of whitespace in the documentation?

Comment: It will result indeed in some extra  white space blocks.